# iOS UITableView Facebook App Style

Tags: uitableview, facebook-apps

I've attached a screenshot of a view from the facebook app. I want to recreate the UI of the left column which looks and behaves like a UITableView.

1. Is this UITableViewStyleGrouped or UITableViewStylePlain. If its grouped, how have they reduced the white space between the section data and the next section header.
2. How have they expanded the UITableView cell to fit across the entire width of the tableview.
3. Or is this html using webviews and just behaves like a UITabelView?

[image: Facebook TableView]

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has an open source library that they have used to develop their iOS app:

http://three20.info/

I believe you may find something here eventually that would allow you to do what Facebook app does.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses the Three20 library for their iOS applications. [ref](http://three20.info/gallery#facebook)

You can find it here: http://three20.info/

I don't know exactly what kind of table the one that you have in the picture is, but I'm pretty sure it's one of them: http://api.three20.info/annotated.php

Comment: The Three20 library was used in the old iOS app.  It's a bit outdated.  I've used it a couple times, it's a good library, but it doesn't have the above in it.